# Stop "your system has run out of application memory" pop up

Tags: macos, big-sur

How do I stop this "Force Quit Applications" — "Your system has run out of application memory" pop up from appearing and interrupting my workflow?

Comment: Which mac and which macOS?

Comment: @lhf big sur, Macbook pro 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when your boot volume is almost completely full and your current workload has overflowed your physical memory, causing some of it to get swapped out to disk.

**This is a dangerous condition** because many user and system processes were not designed or tested under out-of-space conditions and frequently end up corrupting data.

To avoid system slowdown and crashes at best, and data loss at worst, you must immediately:

1. **Quit** as many apps as possible.
2. *(Optional but highly recommended)* Reboot into Recovery and run **Disk First Aid** on your boot volume to fix any corruption that may have occurred.
3. **Free up space** on your drive. Try to keep at least 10% free at all times. This will prevent a recurrence of the issue and also reduce file fragmentation as a bonus.
4. You may (in addition to #3 which is absolutely necessary in all cases) want to invest in upgrading to more DRAM if your system is capable of it. It sounds like your workflow frequently exceeds physical memory and this would help reduce slowdowns due to swap.

Comment: What gunk would you suspect my harddrive to be accummulating? I haven't installed anything in forever, and I delete all of Downloads (I use this dir for any files I save temporarily before re-sending over the internet) and empty trash frequently.

Comment: @theonlygusti You are asking a very broad question and there are very many resources here and elsewhere on the Internet to help you answer the real question that you are asking: "What's taking up space on my drive?" I won't go down that rabbit hole here. The only thing that I will say is that one of (very, very) many possibilities is what I mentioned in my answer to your original question: There may be one or more processes that are consuming large amounts of memory and causing lots of swapfiles to be created, thus eating your otherwise-ample storage.