# How to use Mail even if harddrive is full?

Tags: macos, mail.app, big-sur

I get the error

> Mail cannot save information about your mailboxes because there isn’t enough space in your home folder.

And have no choice but to quite Mail.

How can I use it anyway?

Comment: Same root cause & same fix as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432571/stop-your-system-has-run-out-of-application-memory-pop-up Free up some space. Your drive is critically over-full.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If you've got no space, then there's nowhere to save new emails or meta-data.

You need to have free space on your storage for your computer to operate correctly. I would suggest 20Gb for a 128Gb drive; 50Gb for 250; 75Gb for a 500; and 100Gb for 1Tb.

You need to remove some of your user files and data to another volume.

Comment: why can't it delete local copies of old emails?

Comment: Because it can't save the database: there's not enough room. One check the Mac has always done, that Windows never used to [though that may have changed in recent years] is that it checks it has space *before* starting an operation. You may argue that it will have enough space *afterwards* but for safety it will keep both versions of any copy/overwite until it has finished the entire operation.

Comment: @theonlygusti The typical size of an email is a few K. You're going to have to delete thousands just to recover a few Megabytes. This is not a Mail problem: it's an everything problem. Start with something big.

Comment: @benwiggy "nowhere to save new emails" if emails are all a few kb large, then surely it can delete local old emails to save new emails?

Comment: @theonlygusti You're trying to argue that it should work differently from the way it actually works. One email might be small, but in writing to the database (which may be large), it may need to make a copy of the DB file. Delete some Gigabytes of stuff!!